# Paint Class to draw Text

Tags: android

I wanted to draw a Text at runtime but I wanted to draw a text that has three words. requirement is these words should stack vertically.

[image]

I am able to draw it for one text - Here is the attempt.

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
        paint.AntiAlias = true;
        paint.Dither = true;
        paint.StrokeWidth = 5;
        paint.SetARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);


        textPaint.AntiAlias = true;
        textPaint.SetARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        textPaint.TextSize = 30;

        string firstText = "Text1";

        textPaint.TextAlign = Android.Graphics.Paint.Align.Center;

        canvas.DrawCircle(centerCircle.X, centerCircle.Y, circleRadius, paint);

        canvas.DrawText(firstText, centerCircle.X, centerCircle.Y, textPaint);

    }
```

I am not getting how to draw next Text2 below - I tried firstText="Text1\nText2" but not successful.

Please FYI - I have just started android using `C# Xamarin.Android`. any help and pointer is appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: use a StaticLayout class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `Y` position of text:

```
canvas.DrawText(firstText, centerCircle.X, centerCircle.Y - 50, textPaint);
canvas.DrawText(secondText, centerCircle.X, centerCircle.Y, textPaint);
canvas.DrawText(thirdText, centerCircle.X, centerCircle.Y + 50, textPaint);
```

If you want to center the text in the circle use `measureText` method of `Paint`.

Comment: Can't it be done in one text string ? This is i also thought of :)

Comment: No, I suppose that's not possible. Because the `DrawText` method draws a text just in specified x,y.